# Pass parameter to URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `DIV` in my `.ASPX` and when I click in this `DIV` I trigger this in my javascript code.

```
$("#btnFiltrar").click(function () {
    var status = "";
    var tipo = "";
    var outros = "";
    $("#divStatusImovel input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") == true) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("status_", "");
            switch (id) {
                case "1":
                    status += "at=t&";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    status += "in=t&";
                    break;
                case "14":
                    status += "ds=t&";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    status += "vnd=t&";
                    break;
                case "7":
                    status += "vndpr=t&";
                    break;
                case "8":
                    status += "vndtr=t&";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    status += "vndtr=t&";
                    break;
                case "9":
                    status += "vndtr=t&";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    $("#divTipoImovel input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") == true) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("tipo_", "");
            switch (id) {
                case "1":
                    tipo += "t1=t&";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    tipo += "t2=t&";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    tipo += "t3=t&";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    tipo += "t4=t&";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    tipo += "t5=t&";
                    break;
                case "7":
                    tipo += "t7=t&";
                    break;
                case "8":
                    tipo += "t8=t&";
                    break;
                case "9":
                    tipo += "t9=t&";
                    break;
                case "14":
                    tipo += "t14=t&";
                    break;
                case "15":
                    tipo += "t15=t&";
                    break;
                case "17":
                    tipo += "t17=t&";
                    break;
                case "145":
                    tipo += "t145=t&";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    $("#divOutrosTipos input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") == true) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("outros_", "");
            switch (id) {
                case "1":
                    outros += "ha=t&";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    outros += "fa=t&";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    outros += "fo=t&";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    outros += "pl=t&";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    outros += "dce=t&";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    var pathname = window.location;
    pathname += "?" + status + tipo + outros;
    pathname = pathname.substring(0, pathname.length - 1);
    alert(pathname);
    window.location = pathname;
});
```

In my last line in this javascript function, I try to take the user to the same page but passing some parameters on my URL but without success, occurs a reload in my page but don't pass the parameters on my URL.

Could anyone help me ?

**UPDATE**

A curiosity, when I put a `debugger` before the `window.location.href` it works

```
var pathname = window.location;
pathname += "?" + status + tipo + outros;
pathname = pathname.substring(0, pathname.length - 1);
debugger;
window.location.href = pathname;
```

Comment: Possibly `window.location.href = window.location.href + pathname`?

Comment: Kinda half-way between a comment and a solution, but you could try `window.location.search = status + tipo + outros;` instead of the last 5 lines of code (not including the `});` line)

Comment: @MackieeE I try this, but the page make a reload and don't pass the parameters in my URL. Would be some like `localhost:5154/Imo/Imovel.aspx?p=1&t=2`

Comment: @DerFlatulator I try this also, but the page make a reload and don't pass the parameters in my URL. Would be some like `localhost:5154/Imo/Imovel.aspx?p=1&t=2`

Comment: If you could add a small fiddle, that'd be awesome =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I put together a jsFiddle with some test markup:

```
<div id="divStatusImovel">
    <input type="radio" id="status_4" name="status">status_4</input>
    <input type="radio" id="status_1" name="status">status_1</input>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="divTipoImovel">
    <input type="radio" id="tipo_9" name="tipo">tipo_9</input>
    <input type="radio" id="tipo_145" name="tipo">tipo_145</input>
</div>
<button id="btnFiltrar">Submit</button>
```

I changed the way the query string is built, and in the end, all you need to do is:

```
var qs_arr = [];
for (prop in qs_items)
    qs_arr.push(prop + "=" + qs_items[prop]);

var qs_str = qs_arr.join("&");

window.location.search = qs_str;
```

This is due to each part of the query string being built with a simple key->value map (object), like so:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("outros_", "");
var id_map = {
    "1" : "ha", "2" : "fa", "3" : "fo",
    "4" : "pl", "5" : "dce"
};
qs_items[id_map[id]] = "t";
```

### See complete [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fEvnq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read variables passed to the URL, this may be able to help you, it's what i use.

```
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
         for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if (pair[0] == variable) { return pair[1]; }
         }
         return (false);
    }
```

for example the url could be something like this: 
www.example.com?area=AC&interval=day

You can then fetch the variables by:
var yourvariable = getQueryVariable("area");

Comment: where is jQuery in it?

Comment: Oh and for the record, this is not my creation, i just simply wanted to pass on what helped me when i faced a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

```
window.location
```

to

```
window.location.href
```